return if list is consecutive within python col
I've got a column within a df labelled a. It contains a list of int values. I want to return if they are consecutive or not.
I can do it passing in a single list but I want to iterate over each row.
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[0,2], [9,11,12], [0,1,2], [10,11,13]]})

def cons(L):
    return all(n-i == L[0] for i,n in enumerate(L))

print(cons(df['a'][0])) # works

df['cons'] = df['a'].apply(cons, axis=1) # error

intended:
              a    cons
0        [0, 2]   False
1   [9, 11, 12]   False 
2     [0, 1, 2]    True
3  [10, 11, 13]   False


You're getting an error, TypeError: cons() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis', because axis isn't a valid keyword argument for Series.apply(), since there's only one axis. In the future, please make a [mre] including the error, and ask a specific question about it. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site after all. Check out the [tour] if you haven't already. for more tips, see [ask].

Duplicate: Trouble passing in lambda to apply for pandas DataFrame: "TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' ". [I already voted to close as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" before realizing there might be existing questions about this, sorry.]

"a list of string values" - Strings? What you're showing are ints. Maybe you simplified your code but forgot to update the text?

Use list comprehension with test if sorted values are same like generated list by minimal and maximal values of lists:
df['cons'] = [sorted(l) == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)) for l in df['a']]
#alternative
df['cons'] = df['a'].apply(lambda l: sorted(l) == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1)))

Another idea is use np.diff for test if difference is 1 for all values:
df['cons'] = [np.all(np.diff(sorted(l)) == 1) for l in df['a']]
#alternative
df['cons'] = df['a'].apply(lambda l: np.all(np.diff(sorted(l)) == 1))

If want use your solution:
def cons(L):

    return all(n-i==L[0] for i,n in enumerate(L))

df['cons'] = df['a'].apply(cons)
#alternative
df['cons'] = [all(n-i==L[0] for i,n in enumerate(L)) for L in df['a']]


print (df)
              a   cons
0        [0, 2]  False
1   [9, 11, 12]  False
2     [0, 1, 2]   True
3  [10, 11, 13]  False


Use itertools.pairwise to compare the successive values:
def cons(L):
    from itertools import pairwise
    return all(a==b-1 for a,b in pairwise(L))

df['cons'] = df['a'].apply(cons)

Output:
              a   cons
0  [10, 11, 12]   True
1  [10, 11, 12]   True
2  [10, 11, 12]   True
3  [10, 11, 13]  False


sorry. The aim of the question doesn't change but I should have made a more accurate example.

@tonydanza123 I see, this was indeed not obvious ;)

@tonydanza123 I updated the answer with a pythonic solution, you shouldn't need to sort (O(n*logn))

You can try that code to solve your issue:
cons=df1.apply(lambda ss:pd.Series(ss[0]).diff().iloc[1:].eq(1).all(),1)
df1.assign(cons=cons)


             a   cons
0        [0, 2]  False
1   [9, 11, 12]  False
2     [0, 1, 2]   True
3  [10, 11, 13]  False

